# I need help in fusing two queries in one function in laravel

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, eloquent

I'm new to laravel and I'm already out of options. How can I actually query two tables in one function? It did not gave me any error but It won't also reflect all the datas in the User Interface. This are the two queries in one function.

```
public function displayAssessment()
    {
        $results = DB::table('grades')
            ->join('subjectblocking', 'grades.blockcode', '=', 'subjectblocking.blockcode')
            ->join('subjects', 'subjectblocking.subjectcode', '=', 'subjects.subjectcode')
            ->select('grades.studentid','subjectblocking.subjectcode','subjects.price')

            ->orWhere(function($query)
            {
                $query->where('grades.studentid', '=', '2013-F0218')
                        ->where('sem', '=', '1')
                        ->where('sy', '=', '2013-2014');
            })
            ->get();

            $results = DB::table('subjects')
            ->join('subjectblocking', 'subjects.subjectcode', '=', 'subjectblocking.subjectcode')
            ->join('grades', 'subjectblocking.blockcode', '=', 'grades.blockcode')
            ->select('subjects.numofunit as total_units','subjects.price as total_tuition')

            ->orWhere(function($query)
            {
                $query->where('grades.studentid', '=', '2013-F0218')
                        ->where('sem', '=', '1')
                        ->where('sy', '=', '2013-2014');
            })
            ->sum('subjects.numofunit','subjects.price');


    return View::make('users.assessment')->with('results', $results);
}
```

This first query is supposed to output the price per subject, The second query is the sum of all the subjects and the sum of the number of units in a specific student.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can run multiple queries in one function. The problem with your code is that you're storing the results of the queries in the same variable `$results`. This means with the second query you override the result from the first.

Try using two different variables instead:

```
$grades = DB::table('grades')
    // ... etc ...

$subjects = DB::table('subjects')
    // ... etc ...

return View::make('users.assessment')->with(array('grades' => $grades, 'subjects' => $subjects));
```

Comment: hi! thanks for taking time answering my question. So how can i call these two different variables in PHP? On my foreach function

Comment: @NattyGuurl Show me your foreach loop and I might be able to answer your question...

Comment: that's how i did it. However it gave me an error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: Ahh. I just looked at your queries a bit closer and your second `subjects` query calculates the sum, so it returns a number. If you want to iterate over all subjects, use `->get()` instead of `->sum(...)`

Comment: yup, because supposed to be the second query will calculate the total price of each subjects. So i have to use sum :c

Comment: If you need help with the query itself, please ask a new question. It's a different problem and would be off topic here. Thanks